# LTC3106 solar harvester example - different resistance values but same ratio

Tags: voltage-divider, comparator, time-constant

I've highlighted the voltage divider on the LTC3106 solar harvester example:

[image]

The [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3106f.pdf) explains that the `RUN` pin is connected to a comparator which enables a certain function of the IC for 0.4 or 0.6V:

[image]

Questions:

- How did they get the relations between \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{RUN}\$? Are there some assumptions made on the current going into the IC?
- The ratio R1/R2 can be achieved by different resistor values. 3MOhm/3Mohm = 3KOhm/3Kohm. What should one take into account when choosing the values?

Comment: Most important is the currents. Those that you are wasting, and those that the chip wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship is simply a voltage divider:
$$ V_{RUN} = V_{IN} \frac{R2}{R1+R2} $$
$$ \Rightarrow  V_{IN} = V_{RUN} \frac{R1+R2}{R2} = V_{RUN}(\frac{R1}{R2}+1) $$
One criteria for the value of R1 or R2 is such that the current through it is much larger the current through the RUN pin to control error. For example, looking up from datasheet, on page 4, RUN Input Current = 10nA max. If you want to cap the error due to RUN Input Current variation to no more than 1%, approximately then:
$$ I_{R2} \gt \frac{10nA}{1\%} = 1uA$$
$$ R2 \lt \frac{0.6V}{1uA} = 600K\Omega$$
You do want the resistance to be high to save power. So going with R2 of around 365K like in the datasheet example (or 600K) should be good for most cases.